# Is anybody using JavaFX

Tags: java, swing

I'm very tempted to use it purely because of its neat Binding APIs, and now that you're able to use it in conjunction with Swing it feels like a natural progression.

The only thing that I can seem its lacking off the bat is a GUI builder (But then according to who you speak to, this isn't necessarily a bad thing!)

Does anybody have any experience with using JavaFX 2.0?

Comment: Consider your audience. What browsers are they running? Can you expect your customers to have Java installed in order to run your JavaFX application? Do they have security concerns? Consider if they have HTML5 capable browsers, Silverlight, or Flash. Aside from that, I am not sure who uses JavaFX. If your project needs to be maintained for a long time, I would take a look at current usage and future growth and support.

Comment: Whatever you do, be aware that there are not many jobs and programmers for it. Java GUI development is an undead niche... I definitely wouldn't want to build my career on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was an avid user of JavaFX 1 (1.0 to 1.3), but I haven't tried JavaFX 2 yet, partly because it is beta, partly because the long wait douched my enthusiasm, partly because there is now lot of stuff to re-learn and mostly because I just lack time...
That, and as pointed out, increased support for Canvas and JavaScript libraries across browser (and better JS performance) made this a lot less appealing. Windows only support (currently) is also a weak point. So is the size of applications (at least until it is integrated to the JVM).

Now, I can see where it can shine (with regard to JS only): speed, and perhaps memory usage. I see nice JavaScript Box2D demos, for example, but even on my modern home computer (as opposed to my old work computer...), I can see significant lags, probably at garbage collection time.

I am still hesitant to invest time there... from a personal point of view; enterprise usage is a very different matter. The strong commitment for a big enterprise (Oracle) add weight to this technology. Well, if I should do JavaFX for work, I would be happy to dive again. ^_^ Even better if it is with Scala! :-D

Comment: Its all in Java now - they're talking about bringing back the javaFX script at some point, but no timeframes have been set yet. Also I think you've hit the nail on the head, with Oracle backing the technology it should definitely be worth consideration

Answer (score 1):

I started using JavaFX a while back as opposed to using Silverlight.  I absolutely loved it, alas the Silverlight integration with my must lucrative platform (Windows) provided quicker to market functionality than I could achieve with Java :(

Comment: I should say that I started with JavaFX when SilverLight was at version 1.

Answer (score -1):

We'have started a graphical analysis tool. The API is quite cool and most features i want are in or easy to implements. We are using scala. 
Packaging and advanced documentation are difficult.